# Add magento 2 module in ubuntu error

Tags: magento2, php, ubuntu, phpstorm, php8.1

Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% < 1 sec 117.0 MiBsyntax error, unexpected token "&", expecting "function" or "const"#0 /var/www/myshop/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(433): Composer\Autoload{closure}()
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#2 /var/www/myshop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists()
#3 /var/www/myshop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#4 /var/www/myshop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#5 /var/www/myshop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#6 /var/www/myshop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#7 /var/www/myshop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()
#8 /var/www/myshop/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()
#9 /var/www/myshop/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1021): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#10 /var/www/myshop/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(275): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#11 /var/www/myshop/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#12 /var/www/myshop/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#13 /var/www/myshop/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#14 {main}

Comment: which magento 2 version is in there? is it compatible with php 8.1?

Comment: magento2.4.4 php version 8.1-fpm

Comment: and have you checked what is in the file? `/var/www/myshop/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(433):` (what is on that 433 line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add below line on /var/www/myshop/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(434)

> echo "Class: ".$file."\n";

After adding please run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command. and check the last compilation file and Review the code of that file. once you found and fix it please remove that line.

Comment: Thanks for your response I have already cleared this error

Comment: I know that but I posted the answer because it helps to another one. And Thank You for your response.